# Apache Nifi How to load JSON with nested array JSON and Call Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: json, oracle, apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi, but I have some JSON data which is an array of data and in each array element, there is another nested array data.

Whilst I am able to get file to load the JSON, where I am struggling is on the following:

- Flatten each array and nested array - there is a problem with the nested array where contains new line characters. I have tried a processor to remove it but it is not being removed
- Pull out the data needed
- The pulled out data to be organised where it can passed as parameters to an Oracle Stored Procedure for executions

I have used Get File, JoltTransformJson, ExecuteSQL, GetAttributes, but what I am not seeing is a structure where for each element in the array of JSON and for the flatten out nested JSON a list of attributes that can passed on to the Stored Procedure.

Can anyone give any step by step guidance?

Below is an email of structure of the JSON to give an idea-

[
{
"app_id":"1",
"date_time":"2020-11-30T12:21:25.447430",
"supplier_name":"abc",
"doc_id":"123345",
"data":" {\n   header {\n      l_Id = { 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 11 }\n      identifer = 123456789\n      country = GB\n      commonIdentifier {\n         ident {\n            opps = 6175\n            etni {\n               format = 1234567\n            }\n         }\n         commonIdentityId = 0\n      }\n      sequence = 0\n      timeStamp = 20201130002255.0Z\n      timeStampQual = timeFound\n   }\n   data {\n      sequence [0] {\n         type = type\n         contents {\n            etni {\n               params {\n                  iD = { 1234567 }\n                  version = version\n                  identifier = 1234567\n                  identifier {\n                     commonidentityid = 30\n                     id {\n                        opps = 6175\n                        netId {\n                           format = 12563412\n                        }\n                     }\n                  }\n                  timeStamp {\n                     localTime {\n                        generaltime = 20201130122255.000Z\n                        BSWT = notProvided\n                     }\n                  }\n                  direction = forward\n                  state = nothing\n                  release = 9\n                  nature = ball\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n",
},
{
"app_id":"1",
"date_time":"2020-11-30T12:21:25.447430",
"supplier_name":"abc",
"doc_id":"123345",
"data":" {\n   header {\n      l_Id = { 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 11 }\n      identifer = 123456789\n      country = GB\n      commonIdentifier {\n         ident {\n            opps = 6175\n            etni {\n               format = 1234567\n            }\n         }\n         commonIdentityId = 0\n      }\n      sequence = 0\n      timeStamp = 20201130002255.0Z\n      timeStampQual = timeFound\n   }\n   data {\n      sequence [0] {\n         type = type\n         contents {\n            etni {\n               params {\n                  iD = { 1234567 }\n                  version = version\n                  identifier = 1234567\n                  identifier {\n                     commonidentityid = 30\n                     id {\n                        opps = 6175\n                        netId {\n                           format = 12563412\n                        }\n                     }\n                  }\n                  timeStamp {\n                     localTime {\n                        generaltime = 20201130122255.000Z\n                        BSWT = notProvided\n                     }\n                  }\n                  direction = forward\n                  state = nothing\n                  release = 9\n                  nature = ball\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n",
}
]

Comment: use splitjson in place of jolt.

Comment: Example given to give you an idea

Comment: it's not a json inside "data". get the name of this format then maybe you could find the parser for it...

Answer (score 0):

there is the [FlattenJSON Processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FlattenJson/index.html)
If you're looking to split the JSON, there is the possibility to use JOLT and some sites such as this [JOLT transformation](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#bucketToPrefixSoup)

Another option could be to split the JSON accordingly and use the split values. I have found that the website https://jsonpath.com/ is helpful for deciding how the split could work.
I know this isnt a step by step, but using the SplitJSON processor and then maybe an ExtractText Processor, you would be able to get the desired information. Without knowing the exact format of the data, and which parts of the data that would be desired, providing an exact step by step will be difficult.

Comment: I have added an example of the JSON I working with

Comment: Here's 1 way:
1) Verify the json using jsonlint.com & it will be seen that the "data":"" field should not have a , after it. (Remove that , after the " for data before the bracket)
2) Using JSONpath.com, put in the new json and which shows that you can parse each record using $.*, which means that after receiving the data in the GetFile Processor, run a SplitJSON processor to get each field in each entry or to specify a specific field, use $.*.{fieldName}
3) After the split, the new flow files will contain the specified json key, which can then be manipulated as desired.