# NiFi How do you flatten an array of JSON with nested elements that contains un-formatted data

Tags: apache-nifi

I am struggling to reformat some JSON data in Apache NiFi.

The JSON contains an array of data and nested in each array is a field that contains data which needs to be reformatted and flatten into each array element. The unformatted data element has newline characters that needs to be stripped out.

What I have done so far is to use these processors:

- Get File - this ok as it is loading the data
- Split JSON
- Replace Text - this is removing the new line character with an empty space
- Evaluate JSON Path
- AttributesToJSON

Unfortunately, I am not getting a new JSON structure, which I can pass on to a database per JSON array element.

The source JSON looks like this -
[
{
"app_id":"1",
"date_time":"2020-11-30T12:21:25.447430",
"supplier_name":"abc",
"doc_id":"123345",
"data":" {\n   header {\n      l_Id = { 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 11 }\n      identifer = 123456789\n      country = GB\n      commonIdentifier {\n         ident {\n            opps = 6175\n            etni {\n               format = 1234567\n            }\n         }\n         commonIdentityId = 0\n      }\n      sequence = 0\n      timeStamp = 20201130002255.0Z\n      timeStampQual = timeFound\n   }\n   data {\n      sequence [0] {\n         type = type\n         contents {\n            etni {\n               params {\n                  iD = { 1234567 }\n                  version = version\n                  identifier = 1234567\n                  identifier {\n                     commonidentityid = 30\n                     id {\n                        opps = 6175\n                        netId {\n                           format = 12563412\n                        }\n                     }\n                  }\n                  timeStamp {\n                     localTime {\n                        generaltime = 20201130122255.000Z\n                        BSWT = notProvided\n                     }\n                  }\n                  direction = forward\n                  state = nothing\n                  release = 9\n                  nature = ball\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n",
},
{
"app_id":"1",
"date_time":"2020-11-30T12:21:25.447430",
"supplier_name":"abc",
"doc_id":"123345",
"data":" {\n   header {\n      l_Id = { 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 11 }\n      identifer = 123456789\n      country = GB\n      commonIdentifier {\n         ident {\n            opps = 6175\n            etni {\n               format = 1234567\n            }\n         }\n         commonIdentityId = 0\n      }\n      sequence = 0\n      timeStamp = 20201130002255.0Z\n      timeStampQual = timeFound\n   }\n   data {\n      sequence [0] {\n         type = type\n         contents {\n            etni {\n               params {\n                  iD = { 1234567 }\n                  version = version\n                  identifier = 1234567\n                  identifier {\n                     commonidentityid = 30\n                     id {\n                        opps = 6175\n                        netId {\n                           format = 12563412\n                        }\n                     }\n                  }\n                  timeStamp {\n                     localTime {\n                        generaltime = 20201130122255.000Z\n                        BSWT = notProvided\n                     }\n                  }\n                  direction = forward\n                  state = nothing\n                  release = 9\n                  nature = ball\n               }\n            }\n         }\n      }\n   }\n}\n",
}
]

I am not sure how I can flatten this out where I can pass this on to a database. Getting rid of the newline does appear to be ok, but how do reformat the unformatted data to be a series of new elements, such as data.header.l_Id and data.header.identifier, etc?

Thanks

Comment: man, you already asked the question. it's not a json in "data". find the format name, or at least the system name that sends this kind of data - probably there is a parser for this format available. otherwise it's close to impossible task...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Nifi How to load JSON with nested array JSON and Call Oracle Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575909/apache-nifi-how-to-load-json-with-nested-array-json-and-call-oracle-stored-proce)

Comment: It is more of a question of what the syntax configuration is to do this as I completely do not know.

Answer (score 0):

To note, you asked a very, very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575909/apache-nifi-how-to-load-json-with-nested-array-json-and-call-oracle-stored-proce/68576530#68576530). Follow the steps provided there to isolate the desired field using the SplitJSON field. The data field, once isolated using a SplitJSON of $.*.data is NOT proper JSON. It will yield a result of something like:
" {\n header {\n l_Id = { 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 11 }\n identifer = 123456789\n country = GB\n commonIdentifier {\n ident {\n opps = 6175\n etni {\n format = 1234567\n }\n }\n commonIdentityId = 0\n }\n sequence = 0\n timeStamp = 20201130002255.0Z\n timeStampQual = timeFound\n }\n data {\n sequence [0] {\n type = type\n contents {\n etni {\n params {\n iD = { 1234567 }\n version = version\n identifier = 1234567\n identifier {\n commonidentityid = 30\n id {\n opps = 6175\n netId {\n format = 12563412\n }\n }\n }\n timeStamp {\n localTime {\n generaltime = 20201130122255.000Z\n BSWT = notProvided\n }\n }\n direction = forward\n state = nothing\n release = 9\n nature = ball\n }\n }\n }\n }\n }\n}\n"

This isnt proper JSON and you would need to make sure that the data is formatted into JSON before it could be parsed as JSON data. Make sure that you not only identify which field needs to be flattened and then make sure that it's in the proper format. There is a [FlattenJSON NiFi Processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FlattenJson/index.html), have you checked about any documentation related to that processor and questions people have asked? It looks like it could solve your problem if the field were in JSON.

Comment: Yes, and I have identified what I want but I am not seeing what I am expecting to see

Comment: Are you unsure why the data field is not Json? I provided a way to flatten the data. If the other question is answered, could it be marked as an accepted solution?

Comment: Basically it is a dump from a log from another system, which has been added to the data element. So, I have to some how reformat it into individual elements to make it easier for database parsing

Comment: Is there an existing NiFi Processor that can do this?  If not, you need to write a custom script. Have you checked the https://community.cloudera.com/ website for their forums to see if there are similar questions or areas that can help?

Comment: I have searched the internet more broadly on this and tried all sorts of things, but to no avail. Unfortunately, my NiFi experience is that of a novice, which why I am reaching out for help

Comment: Is a process that you can use to out this and tell how to map and then readd the new elements? This is what I tried with the Attributes to Json

Comment: You need to convert the data fields to json or another format which you can then flatten. The data isn’t ready to flatten. I would recommend knowing how to flatten data in NiFi and then getting the data into that field. The data field in the array isn’t in valid json format. if we’re not providing an answer, you could try to do more specific searching as there might an already existing answer.  If the prior question solved your question at that time, you can mark it as the answer